# Cyclic Partisan Nim Variant

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory

This game is played with a sequence of heaps and a position marker, where each heap is owned by exactly one player. The game ends when a player has removed all objects from their own heaps, and this player wins with score equal to the number of remaining objects. Other players lose with score equal to minus the number of objects they still own. Play consists of players cyclically taking turns, where (for the 2-player version) they choose to either:

- Move the position marker forward to any non-empty heap they own, and remove exactly one object from that heap.
- Reset the position marker back to the beginning, before any heaps. (Only valid if the previous player did not reset - this ensures the game is finite.)

**What is the optimal strategy for each player in the 2-player version, given an arbitrary initial state?**

A state can be specified by:

- A sequence of (size, owner) integer pairs representing the heaps
- A non-negative integer representing the position marker (with the sequence indexed starting from one)
- An integer representing the player about to move
- A Boolean representing whether the previous player chose to reset

---

So far I have noticed the maximal score seems to eventually follow an arithmetic progression under consistent patterns of adding to the heaps. However, there is a certain region of states with more unstable behaviour. The main problem is the position marker, since without it the game would become trivial.

---

Update: I have generated the maximum scores for player $0$ with the initial state

$$
\left( \begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
\!\!\!& 3 &   & x &   & 5 &   & y &   \!\\
\!\!\!&   & 6 &   & 9 &   & 2 &   & 4 \!
\end{array} \right)_{\text{P}0, \top}
$$

as $x$ and $y$ range from $1$ to $11$.
[image: contour plot of maximum scores]
Solid contours represent positive score and dashed contours represent negative score. Interestingly, it can be seen that the behaviour changes only near when two heaps have the same size.

Further, I am fairly confident this maximum score formula

$$
\left( \begin{array}{c|ccc}
\!\!\!& h_1 &     & h_3 \!\\
\!\!\!&     & h_2 &     \!
\end{array} \right)_{\text{P}0, \top}
\,\to\,
\left\{ \begin{array}{lrrcr}
h_2 - h_1     & \text{if} & h_2 - h_1 < 0 & \text{and} & h_3 - h_2 + 1 \ge 0   \\
h_2 - h_1 + 1 & \text{if} & h_3 - h_1 + 1 \ge 0 & \text{and} & h_2 - h_1 \ge 0 \\
h_3 - h_1 + 1 & \text{if} & h_3 - h_1 + 1 < 0 & \text{and} & h_3 - h_2 + 1 < 0
\end{array} \right.
$$

works for all values of $h_i > 0$, and also including when $h_3 = 0$ or $h_2 = h_3 = 0$. In general I think the function would have to be piecewise linear with coefficients in $\{ -1, 0, +1 \}$ and satisfy a *heap merge invariance property*, meaning for example that $M(h_1, 0, h_3) = M(h_1 + h_3, 0, 0) = M(0, 0, h_1 + h_3)$.

Comment: what is the meaning of "optimal strategy" when there are more than two players ?

Comment: @mercio Sorry, I meant optimal strategy for two players. What are the options for more than two players? For a given player, it could be to maximise their score if a win is guaranteed, otherwise minimise the variance among the players' scores.

Comment: By the way, the final Boolean in your state seems a bit redundant, since during play the position marker is before any heaps iff the previous player reset it. Or do you want to allow your arbitrary starting position to be inconsistent in this respect, so that a starting position may or may not allow a reset move regardless of the starting location of the marker?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes it annoys me, but here is why I have left it there: 1) the special case exists either way, so may as well make it explicit; 2) it is only a Boolean in the 2-player case, in the n-player generalisation it can take on n values; and...

Comment: @JaapScherphuis 3) Whenever there is an empty heap, I delete it and merge the adjacent heaps to reduce complexity if possible (for 2 players this makes the heap ownership alternate). Thus if the first player deletes the first heap, then the second player will not know if they can reset the position marker, unless they have the Boolean. Then there are three options: leave empty heaps and no Boolean, remove empty heaps and add Boolean, or remove empty heaps and add a phantom empty heap at the beginning. The middle option seems to be the most convenient.

Comment: The heap merging of (3) makes a lot of sense, but I see that as more of an implementation issue than something intrinsic to game play as described. No matter. Thanks for explaining. The more I think about the game the trickier it is. Resetting is the only reason for the players not removing objects at the same rate. So you want the other player to reset, and owning the last heap means you won't be forced to reset. Does that mean you'd take always from the last pile? It would deplete quicker and when empty give the advantage to the other player for a while. It's tricky.

Comment: Very interesting question. Could you say more about what you've already tried? I didn't understand what you said about an arithmetic progression - could you expand on it?

Comment: @alcana I have added an example. The arithmetic progressions I was referring to amount to the lines in the image.

Comment: That's interesting. Very speculatively: it seems that it is advantageous to have objects further down the chain and disadvantageous to have them nearer the beginning. Could the optimal strategy be as simple as taking from the first available pile? I've done some limited random experimentation and haven't yet found a counterexample to that hypothesis, do you know of one?

Comment: @alcana I think the comment by @ JaapScherphuis explains why that is not likely to work. An explicit counterexample is (|1, 1, 1). I added a formula for 3 heaps, and I have one for 4 heaps, although it is very messy and has redundancy.

Comment: Yes I see that (|1, 1, 1) is a counterexample. Interesting to investigate the special cases of 3 heaps, 4 heaps etc. I wonder if some kind of induction argument could prove some strategy optimal...?

Comment: @alcana I really don't know, that's why I asked here (and it is also an interesting question). My current way of thinking is to use the optimal score to indirectly derive the optimal strategy. I know roughly _where_ the special cases are, and that they have a kind of 'refractive' behaviour, but not the details of the refraction. Maybe it can be expressed as a composition of base refractions? Induction is great once you actually have something to prove.

Comment: Ok sounds like a good line of enquiry. Out of interest, how are you getting the optimal scores? E.g. are you using some kind of minimax algorithm to solve the game in specific cases?

Comment: @alcana Yes, minimax + cache (20 GB), in Python. Do you see a way to prove/disprove that there is only one connected component for each score?